# Storyboard flow design iOS?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I've been asked to setup a small app for a client and was wondering if anyone could briefly describe the best way to layout the app. Not looking for code or anything, simply ideas on how best to achieve what the client wants. This will be my first commercial app and will be doing it within Xamarin using `Storyboards` and then later on I'll have to reproduce the app for Android.

The brief asks for a app with an initial login screen - *No title/nav bar* as below.

[image: Login screen]

Then once logged in the user is based on a "homepage" welcome screen which has a Sidebar/hamburger menu proving them with options. (a) Scan a QR code (b) Request a ID verification check (c) Drivers license photo check.

The apps are going to be for both phones and tablets.

[image: Homepage welcome screen]

[image: Sidebar nav]

None of the pages were wireframed with any *navbar* or *toolbar/tabs*, simply pages which are linked via *actions/events* or button links or the sidebar.

What I have setup currently is a simple single ViewController with the login items on.

Is it best to create all the separate View Controllers as separate entities and link via Segues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, whenever possible, you should decouple your program into sub modules, which will benefit greatly through out the whole app development process. Your program will be **easier to develop, modify, debug and test**.

So yes, please put each function/module into their own view controllers.

In your case, broadly speaking, you can arrange the view controller hierarchy like:

1. **login view controller**, you can present modally from the following container view controller;
2. **A container view controller** that contains (a) Scan a QR code (b) Request a ID verification check (c) Drivers license photo check, each of which is in their own view controller.

Also note that creating a custom container view controller, there are a few details for you to concern, please look online. To begin with, check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) from apple.